# JQuery Validation plugin tweaking

Tags: jquery, validation

Is it possible to not have a message appear next to a missing field, but instead set a css rule to change the background colour of the field?

I tried looking, and Im sorry that I have nothing to prove (for all the really hardcore SO users with triggerhappy downvote fingers), but I could not find anything.

My form is really tight and if the message appears then if throws out the architecture whole form.

Bollow is what I have in place now. Ant it works like I said, but I would like to replace the messages with color.

**Validation Rules**

> ```
>     var addStoreValidator; //scope - to reset form
>     /* add new store to database */
>     $('#addEditSave').click(function(){
>         addStoreValidator = $("#storeEditFrm").validate({
>             rules: {
>                     "store_name": "required",
>                     "street_name": "required",
>                     "city_name": "required",
>                     "province_name": "required",
>                     "country_name": "required",
>                     "phone": "required",
>                     "store_email": {
>                         required: true,
>                         email: true
>                     },
>                     "ip_address": {
>                         required: true,
>                         ipv4: true
>                     }
>                 },
>                 messages: {
>
>                 }
>         });
> ```

**If the Form is Valid:**

> ```
>         if ($("#storeEditFrm").valid()){
>             $.ajax({
>                 type: "POST",
>                 url: './inc/storeScripts.php?argument=addStore',
>                 data: { name: $("#store_name").val(),
>                         street: $("#street_name").val(),
>                         suburb: $("#suburb_name").val(),
>                         city: $("#city_name").val(),
>                         province: $("#province_name").val(),
>                         country: $("#country_name").val(),
>                         phone: $("#phone").val(),
>                         email: $("#store_email").val(),
>                         fax: $("#fax").val(),
>                         ip_address: $("#ip_address").val()
>                 },
>                 dataType: "json"
>             })
> ```

Comment: share your html and the validator code that you have... also try to edit the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7Kscj/) to recreate the problem

Comment: Yeah, you can use the `funCall` validator to do this. Don't have enough time to show you but look around this validator.

Comment: @KevinLabécot - Thanks. I am going to have a look at that yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an expert in validator, but you can do something like

```
input.myerror {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

then

```
var validator = $('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        x: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {},
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {},
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass('myerror')
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass('myerror')
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d32f8ozh/)

Comment: This works great. If I dont get the VALIDATOR plugin going, this will be the accepted answer

Comment: This solution is using validator plugin

Comment: My mistake. did not think you could include the plugin like that in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use the change the `invalidHandler` and use the `invalidHandler` to update the css [(jquery validate options)](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) :

```
$(".selector").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
        return true;
    },
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        $.each(errorList, function() {
            // update css value for element
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This sounds easy enough. Ill give it a go, Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In my experience you type of code works, but i like to work with custom JS class in this type of "plugins", here follow a class that is used on Magento Community and it uses prototype, but you could easily change to jQuery.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/master/lib/web/varien/form.js

Hope it helps, this class is really well made, you can follow it that your work will be more extensible than you could ever imagine.

Comment: This is like demolishing a building to kill a fly. Way to powerful for my needs. Not taking anything away from this class is look like its *more extensible than you could ever imagine.* . Thanks anyway